# How can Wolfenstein Enemy Teritory with dependency on libgtk1.2 be installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, games, ppa, gtk

Hey,
Im trying to install Wolfenstein E.T however it comes up with this error message when running, Saying its missing Libgtk-1.2. In the repos there is only libgtk2.0 any ideas how i can get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either download and compile [libgtk-1.2](http://www.gtk.org/download-linux.html) or update and recompile the game (don't think this is a real possibility, but in theory it works.)
You can google for instructions on how to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

The enemy-territory package which is available from http://www.playdeb.net does not depend on libgtk1.2 .