# No sound on Wolfenstien: ET

Tags: sound, games

I am trying to play wolfenstien ET and everything works fine, except the sound... I can't hear anything, doesn't matter if it speakers or headphones..

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Obvious question, but I assume your system sound works when wolf ET is not running, also what version of Ubuntu is it running on?

Comment: yes system sound works, even works on other games...12.04

Comment: Also, you may want to edit your question to clarify that you're running the [GNU/Linux version (provided by the developer, idSoftware)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnemyTerritory), and not the Windows version in Wine. (Assuming the GNU/Linux version *is* the one you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

If your system sound is working perfectly and your sound issues are game specific, its possible you may have unmet dependenies. (Have you considered this?)

`libgtk1.2` must  be installed

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk1.2
```

Also even if you are running 64-bit you need top install the 32-bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I tried to recreate this issue on a friends machine last night (as i knew he plays Enemy territory) with out success and i am all out of ideas if my answer here isnt the solution.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I can't get libgtk1.2 to install, tells me the package is not available... any idea why?

Comment: @TheX  Trust you used the sudo apt-get install libgtk1.2 in terminal

Comment: @TheX Just found another question here on AU with the same problem.  Check it out in might help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/1846/how-can-wolfenstein-enemy-teritory-with-dependency-on-libgtk1-2-be-installed-on

Comment: Yes to the first question, and I will check out the link.

Comment: This did not work for me.